# Not able to send message to AWS SQS using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I have setup an EC2 instance in the private subnet and assigned it an IAM role with permissions to send messages to my SQS queue. Using AWS CLI I'm able to send messages properly but when I do it through a program(tried node and java) I'm getting "connection timedout" exceptions. As per the AWS docs, SDKs should automatically get credentials when using roles. Any clues where things could be going wrong ?

Comment: Do you have NAT gateway or SQS interface endpoints in your private subnet?

Comment: May I ask why it is concluded IAM issue not connection? What tests have been done with what configuration from within the EC2 instance? I believe no profile for the account in the EC2? Probably better to put code, environment, reproducible steps to get help?

Comment: @Marcin we do have a NAT gateway. If it wasn't then even CLI wouldn't have been successful

Comment: @mon I didn't conclude that it was an IAM issue: was just asking for some pointers where things could be going wrong. There is indeed a profile setup for the EC2 instance. CLI is able to send message using that profile.

Comment: I guess EC2 profile may not be working. Please double check. If properly configured, you should not need profile setup.

Comment: Please update your question with details. “Cli work but java does not” is too ambiguous. Such as profile is created in EC2 or not, the detail of IAM role permissions attached as EC2 profile. I am afraid otherwise not much help come to such question?

Comment: Since “private subnet” is mentioned, how SDK can reach AWS service endpoint, NAT+routing from the private subnet. Or VPC endpoint for SQS is created. AWS región used because some AWS service does not support endpoint in some region. Those details isolate the possible causes.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I was able to solve this issue. We needed to configure proxy in our SDK.